# How can I apply for an Irish tourist visa?

Tags: visas, ireland, iraqi-citizens

I have an Iraqi passport and I need to travel to Ireland. I am just 14 years old, and am traveling by myself from Dubai to Ireland. Should I have a visa or not? And what type of visa should I have? And how can I apply for it? And how long does it take to be done?

Comment: Why do you think you need a transit visa? Transit visas are usually when you're not staying in a place, but just passing through.  Generally if you're visiting a country, you'll just want a tourist visa?

Comment: Do you have your [parents' consent](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Processing%20Guidelines%20for%20applications%20made%20on%20basis%20of%20Directive.pdf/Files/Processing%20Guidelines%20for%20applications%20made%20on%20basis%20of%20Directive.pdf) to apply for the visa?

Comment: what do you mean my parent's consent?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you need a visa.

The Irish Embassy has a "[visa faciliation office](http://irishsocietydubai.com/irish-in-uae/embassy/)" in Dubai at 4th Floor Monarch Tower
No. 1 Sheikh Zayed Road (Opposite Trade Centre) - that's where you need to go.

As for what type of visa you need and how the application process looks like, that depends on why and how long you want to travel to Ireland. The embassy's website has [more details information](http://www.embassyofireland.ae/home/index.aspx?id=85100), or the people at the office will tell you.